# Tooling API to fetch Duplicate Objects/Fields

Tags: api, fields, custom, object, tooling

I want to fetch duplicate object and field information before deploying my package to another org. 
Is there any pre build tool or tooling API reference that can resolve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate object and field information"? What type of package are you deploying?

Comment: @DavidReed I am deploying managed package, and receiving duplicate error when deploying package to another org where field is already there.